# How long will it take for a dog to adjust to a new home

Tags: dogs, stress, house-moving

When moving home it affects us all, including pets.

It can take people a while to feel happy in a new home.

How long is normal before a dog returns to its confident old behaviors?

Answer (score 3):

This will definitely vary dog to dog and can even affect their house training since they don't know where to go. If your dog seems to be taking a while to adjust introduce them to the new house like you would a puppy. Confine them to the most 'lived in' room first. Once they get used to that add more rooms.

Show them where they need to relieve themselves consistently and be easy on them if they do go in the 'wrong' place - they probably don't know where the right place is yet.

Answer (score 1):

Each dog is different. Some dogs are confident and adaptable and will adjust in a matter of a few days. Slow to adjust dogs can take weeks.